# i have a problem with adding firebase SDK to my flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, sdk, build.gradle

[I have added the codes as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8hPC.png)

when i add the id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false to the android/build.gradle It throws me an error says
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

and when i add second code which is the id 'com.google.gms.google-services' It throws me an error says
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Flutter, you should NOT follow those steps because those are for Native Android developers. I've got stuck there before too.

Instead, you should follow these steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android